# CakePHP. Where to put scripts that populate database?

Tags: database, cakephp, scripting

I am working on a CakePHP project that has a database populated from multiple text files. I didn't write most of the scripts that populate database (they are written in Perl/Python). There are a couple PHP scripts though that I created that alter some data in a database according to information in some additional text files. My question is where all of these scripts fit the best in CakePHP application. What would be the common practice that would allow user to use my PHP script to modify info in database again if necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would allow user to use my PHP script to modify info in database again if necessary?

Since you're dealing with the database the obvious choice here would be to create a model that approved users can utilize to alter your database.

Here's a very simple example of what I might do:

```
class Alter extends AppModel {

    // tells the model not to use a database table
    public $useTable = false;

    public function do_stuff() {
        // your code to include scripts and alter database with, I'm assuming, raw SQL
    }

}
```

Then you'd need a controller for that model

```
class AltersController extends AppController {

    public function edit($param1, $param2) {
         // code here to access the model
         $this->Alter->do_stuff();
    }

}
```

Now your users can edit the database as needed.  Your data logic also is properly encapsulated in the model, where I believe it should go.

Edit:

In regards to OP's question.  [Here's an article that talks about using Perl with PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1712).

Comment: So if I have Perl scripts that process CSV files and populate database accordingly how do I incorporate them in my CakePHP model logic?

Comment: Are you asking how to run a Perl script from CakePHP?  If so, that's beyond my purview.  I was answering in relation to including PHP scripts.  I'm sure there's somebody smarter than me to talk about Perl.  I'll edit my answer to clarify I was referring to the PHP script aspect of your question.

Comment: Thank you! My bad: two questions in one post here.... Just to clarify I have a script written in plain PHP that has some raw SQL and some PHP code (open/read CSV file, process db data etc.), it was written before I decided to use the framework. So I guess now I need to create methods in Alter class to work with database and put the rest of my PHP script in AltersController (process CSV then $this->Alter->do_stuff();)

Answer (score 0):

As cakePHP is MVC you should place all the scripts that your talking about in the controllers.
So lets say you table is called: "posts"
All the CRUD functions should be in the model - all access to the models should be from the controllers. Basically, the logic that talks to the DB should be in the Model, the functions that call that logic should be in the Controllers. I hope this better explains what I meant before I edited the answer.

Comment: If anything he should be placing this functionality into a model, not a controller.  I also don't think he wants to know how to setup a controller associated with a model/table but instead how to use raw SQL to update an entire database.

Comment: As cakePHP does most of the work automatically, I still think the answer is to put the functions in the controller, the controllers are the part of the whole that tell the models what to do and when. So if you want to do something, you put it in the controller, and that tells the model to do what ever it is that needs to be done.

Comment: Yes, you have to put the code in the controller to tell the model what to do.  But, your controller should effectively be 1 line of code to do what OP wants, `$this->ModelName->model_action()`.  Your answer implies that he should do all the business/data logic in the controller, in my opinion this is breaking the MVC pattern.  You now have data logic in a controller.  What if I need to use this same logic in a different controller?  I've suddenly found myself in a situation where I have to duplicate code or load multiple controllers per request.